# unable to execute a batch file from the task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am struggling with this since yesterday, i have created a Batch file -a simple one- which simply will try to read the logs of a windows scheduled task and based on searching for correct 'Last result' will log 0 or 1 to a log file . The Batch file run perfectly .
But i want to schedule this Batch file to be ran each 2 minutes ,

so i create a scheduled task that ran this batch file ;When i force starting the scheduled task, I don't see any errors in the task scheduler history, but at the same time my Batch file is not executed.

What i tried, 
-i made sure i am running the scheduled task with option "run with highest privileges" , 
-i made sure i have correct permissions (still not sure)
I tried using process monitor and didn't see any access issues 
so nothing happens when i run my task i am going crazy,

This is the content of my Batch file :

```
     SET LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log
    call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
    exit /b 0
```

`:Logit
:: The rest of your code
:: ....
for %%A in (DownloadToIngest.log) do set fileSize=%%~zA
echo %fileSize%>logall.log
if %fileSize% GTR 419430400 (break>DownloadToIngest.log)

schtasks /QUERY /FO LIST /V /tn DownloadToIngest> DownloadToIngestOutput.log
findstr /m "Last Result:                          0" DownloadToIngestOutput.log
IF %errorlevel%==0 (>>DownloadToIngest.log  echo 1) ELSE >>DownloadToIngest.log  echo 0<code>`

Comment: Use your username and password in the scheduled task during testing, and if it works simply by doing that then it a permissions/access issue.

Comment: Hi foxidrive , thanks for your response , can you explain what do you mean by 'Use your username and password in the scheduled task during testing' , i have created the task with and administrator account and i have entered pass for it .if its what you mean

Comment: Does the task scheduler say "task completed successfully"? What does the history tell you **after you refresh it with F5?** Also make sure you have the path to your batch file defined correctly in the Task Scheduler. I have also experienced similar problems and I found that it's better to use just the name of batch file and then use the "start in" option to point to the fully qualified path where your batch file is located.

Comment: Thanks Vector (Look Vector's comment) , the issue was solved by :
instead of referencing the path and file name under 'Program/script'
adding the name of script under 'Program/script'
and the path to the file under 'Start in (optional)'[I am new here so i couldn't mark the question as answered yet]

Comment: Mofi i was going to answer my question but the rules were that i can do that after 8 hours , then the weekend came and got busy with other stuff , and i think no body knows if this question will be or not useful for other people ,I saw similar question in other forums but with different responses that didn't work for me (In other words the question is not useful for you but maybe it is for other people)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Vector (Look Vector's comment) , the issue was solved by : instead of referencing the path and file name under 'Program/script' adding the name of script under 'Program/script' and the path to the file under 'Start in (optional)'